# C# LINQ - Split Rows into Two Rows

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Sorry for the possibly stupid question, but I have this `Ienumerable<>` set as such

[image: Dataset]

I need to split out the name and percent into separate rows, and duplicate the ProductId and RowIndex for those rows (I know it's not efficient but it's what needs to be done). And probably an new field to specify which data that combined row has.

So for example,

`ProductId, Name       , Percent, RowIndex
 2301283  , PLACEHOLDER, 12.20  , 1`

should turn into this:

`ProductId, DataType, Value      , RowIndex
 2301283  , Name    , PLACEHOLDER, 1
 2301283  , Percent , 12.20      , 1
 etc etc`

Also, they can't be nested in other lists or enumerables or anything, if that makes sense.

Is that possible within LINQ?

Comment: Do you need single resulting sequence, or there must be two sequences: first one with Name, second one - with Percent? In case of single sequence describe data type you want to contain data.

Comment: .Select(entireRow => Tuple.Create(entireRow.Left, entireRow.Right).UnZip();

Comment: @SeM to get to the point where the LINQ data is shown in the table above took a very long time on its own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you want to transform each `GI` object into 2 new objects, and flatten all these pairs into one enumerable. Hopefully I understood you correctly.

I think [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) can do the job.

```
yourEnumerable.SelectMany(x => new[] {
    new { ProductId = x.ProductId, DataType = "Name", Value = x.Name, RowIndex = x.RowIndex },
    new { ProductId = x.ProductId, DataType = "Percent", Value = x.Percent, RowIndex = x.RowIndex }
})
```

Comment: This seems to have done it, thank you so much! This was causing me issues for a few hours now!

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ `.Select` method and a new class. In order to do it efficiently you could use `Tuple<T1, T2>` structure:

```
public class AttributeData
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int RowIndex { get; set; }
}

yourEnumerable.Select(x => 
     Tuple.Create(
         new AttributeData
         { 
            ProductId = x.ProductId,
            DataType = "Name",
            Value= x.Name,
            RowIndex= x.RowIndex
         },
         new AttributeData
         { 
            ProductId = x.ProductId,
            DataType = "Percent",
            Value= x.Percent,
            RowIndex= x.RowIndex
         }
      ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//list is your data collection
//newlist is the result
var newlist = new List<dynamic>();
list.ForEach(w =>
{
    newlist.Add(
        new {w.ProductID,DataType="Percent",Value=w.Percent,w.RowIndex}
    );
    newlist.Add(
        new {w.ProductID,DataType="Name",Value=w.Name,w.RowIndex}
    );
});
newlist.Dump();
```

[image]

Hope it help you :-)

Comment: you're enumerating list twice here. since .Select is actually a functor, `select (g) . select(f)` will ALWAYS be equal to the `select(g . f)` which is twice as fast (in terms of completed operations in the worst case).

Comment: EmrahSüngü Süngü, Sereja Bogolubov thanks , i fix it

Answer (score 0):

try like this

This will flat out result with `SelectMany`

```
   var data = (from entity in Entities
    select new [] {
         new { entity.ProductId, DataType = "Name", Value= entity.Name, entity.RowIndex},
         new { entity.ProductId, DataType = "Percentage", Value= entity.Percentage, entity.RowIndex},
    }).SelectMany(e=> e);
```

or

this will give you list with each element contains Name and Percetnage row in it

```
   var data = (from entity in Entities
    select  new {
         NameEntity = new { entity.ProductId, DataType = "Name", Value= entity.Name, entity.RowIndex},
         PercentageEntity = new { entity.ProductId, DataType = "Percentage", Value= entity.Percentage, entity.RowIndex},
    });

  foreach(var d in data) {
    //d.NameEntity
    //d.PercentageEntity  
  }
```